# How to create a debug apk in react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I tried every piece of information available on the net to create a debug apk file for react-native-expo but it is not working.
Please help if some knows any solution...

Comment: Did you try all the steps from here? https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps

Comment: I have seen that doc but it's all about creating a signed apk

Comment: any solutions about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the new **Expo Run Commands** available from SDK 41.

https://blog.expo.dev/introducing-expo-run-commands-835ae8da4813

One of the uses cases is "Test and **debug** your standalone app locally, without the limitations of Expo Go".